# Use target mode to pull data from a hard disk encrypted with FileVault?

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, high-sierra, filevault, target-disk-mode

I got this message on a MacBook Pro 2012:

> path /system/installation/packages/osinstall.mpkg appears to be missing or damaged

The first thing to do is to safe data. The hard disk is encrypted with FileVault.

Is it possible to plug it to another MacBook Pro (running High Sierra or El Capitan) and pull the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

Boot the Mac you want the data from into target disk mode, https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462. Connect the two Macs and wait. You should be prompted for the file vault password. After you enter the correct file vault password wait some more. After a few minutes the other mac's drive should mount on the desktop. Now copy over any files you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you, I will try on tomorrow and I will say if it's ok or not.

Comment: OK, it was like you said, I had to put the password of the disk.  Unfortunately it was impossible for me to get data, but what you said was correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, however here are the steps without having to leave this forum.

Connect the two computers with a FireWire or Thunderbolt cable.

On the Mac you want to use as the disk in target disk mode, do one of the following:

If the computer is off, start it up while pressing and holding the T key.

If the computer is on, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Startup Disk, then click Target Disk Mode.

When the computer has started up, a disk icon appears on the desktop of the other computer.

Transfer files by dragging them to and from the disk.

Eject the disk by dragging its icon to the Trash.

While you drag, the Trash icon changes to an Eject icon.

On the Mac you used as a disk, push the power button to shut it down, then disconnect the cable.